# Notepad++ : Remove everything except digit and hyphen pattern

Tags: windows, replace, find, pattern-matching, notepad++

Notepad++ : I have a file with phone numbers, all are of type 123-123-1234
I need to match the pattern any3digitsDASHany3digitsDASHany4digits and delete anything that does not match this pattern

### I HAVE

```
  XL/XXL  1 
 349 "
" 
242 8 . . 
. 22140 
  089-247-3065

 XL/XXL  1 
 349 "
"  
206/1 .6 . .
. 30000
 092-273-6125
```

### I WANT

```
089-247-3065

092-273-6125
```

Thanks in advance for your kind assistance !

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this?  Are there any constraints on how this should be done?

Comment: I searched about +20 examples of string or pattern matching, but could not find anything that would accomplish what I need, which is basically to remove everything in the file that is not xxx-xxx-xxxx (where x is a digit and '-' needs to be retained too as part of the pattern)

Comment: Will there ever be more than 1 phone number on the same line?

Comment: No, only a single phone number per line, and the phone number is clear of any other text/characters, it is purely a 3-digit hyphen 3-digit hyphen 4-digit format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\G.*?(?<!\d)(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}(?!\d)|\z)`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\G                  # restart from last match position
.*?                 # 0 or more any character
(?<!\d)             # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't digit before
(                   # start group 1
  \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4} # the string you're searching for
  (?!\d)            # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't digit after
 |                # OR
  \z                # end of file
)                   # end of group
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Hello Toto, absolutely perfect. Definition, application/method/options to select, Before and After screenshots. Tested, provides exactly what I was hoping for. Many, many thanks for your time, your skills and your presentation method. Merci a toi, cocorico !

Comment: Note that, if a phone number has a digit immediately in front of it, this won't pick that phone number up.  Probably not an issue, but not explicitly ruled out by OP.

Comment: Nice + just wondered if `(?:\A|\G)` was redundant because `\G` matches already start of string.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Thank you. You're right, because the `/s` flag. Without it, it's mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o '\b[[:digit:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{4\}\b' file
089-247-3065
092-273-6125
```

Comment: Wich tool do you use ? I demonstrate `grep` here

Comment: notepad++ my apologies if my understanding is below par. I assumed that I should place your command in the search -> replace area of Notepad++

Comment: You should mention this at the beginning. But with windows10, grep should be available

Answer (score 1):

Replacing what is found by this regular expression:

```
^.*(\d{3}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}).*$
```

And replacing it with

```
\1
```

in Notepad++ will isolate all of the phone numbers in their lines, but leave the lines w/o phone numbers intact.  Those can be removed by replacing this regular expression:

```
^(?!\d{3}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}).*$
```

with nothing.

Comment: Thanks Scott, indeed it removes everything before the xxx-xxx-xxxx pattern, and as you confirmed, it leaves everything else intact. Is there a way to only match and retain the pattern, removing everything else that does not match please?